# Why can't I use renice to increase a process' nice value?

Tags: nice, priority

From `man renice`:

> Users other than the super-user may only alter the priority of processes
>    they own, and **can only monotonically increase their ``nice value'' (for
>    security reasons)** within the range 0 to PRIO_MAX (20) [...]

So, I can `renice` my own processes upwards (give them lower priority) but never downwards:

```
$ renice 10 22316
22316 (process ID) old priority 0, new priority 10
$ renice 9 22316
renice: failed to set priority for 22316 (process ID): Permission denied
```

Why is this? I can understand why normal users cannot set nice values lower than 0, but why since I can decrease the priority to 10 can't I increase it again to 9? What "security reason" is there for this? I have the right to launch a process with a nice value of 9, so why can't I renice it to 9?

---

EDIT: I should learn to scroll down. Turns out this is listed as a bug in `man renice`:

```
BUGS
     Non super-users can not increase scheduling priorities of their own
     processes, even if they were the ones that decreased the priorities 
     in the first place.
```

That's even more confusing. If they consider this behavior to be a bug, why not change it? The `renice` command appeared in 4.0BSD which I think is from 1980. This should be very easy to fix so on the one hand they seem to have chosen to leave it and on the other they list it as a bug.

Comment: Because some priorities higher than 0 may be enforced by a system process or a security module and should never be decreased by the user (and there is no control fine enough to define the minimal niceness of a given user process other than the fixed value 0)? Not an answer as I'm not sure but a guess.

Comment: [Same question on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510718).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since linux 2.6.12, that depends on the value of the RLIMIT_NICE limit (`ulimit -e`). Which can take values from 0 to 40. That limit is more the limit on the *priority* of the process (the greater that number, the higher the priority a user can set for a process).

You'll notice the default value is 20 on ubuntu 10.04 and 0 in Debian jessie for instance.

A value of `n` for that limit means that a process without the CAP_NICE capability can only *increase* a process priority to up to `n`, which means decrease niceness down to a niceness of `20 - n`. So for a value of 0, that means no non-privileged  user can lower the niceness below 20, so no non-privileged user can lower the niceness.

With a value of 20, non-privileged users can decrease the niceness back to 0.

It's up to the administrator to choose whether they allow users to lower their process priority, and to what level by setting the hard limit for that.

As to why an administrator may not want users to lower their process priority, see [Flup's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/119305/22565).

Comment: Ah! So it is configurable! OK, that makes more sense, thanks.

Comment: "values from 0 to 40. [...] You'll notice the default value is 20 on ubuntu 10.04 and 0 in Debian jessie for instance." -> Interesting, hard/soft ulimits for me are indeed 0 on debian jessie. I can raise up to 20 but beyond that I get "bash: ulimit: scheduling priority: cannot modify limit: Invalid argument", negative values aren't accepted either.

Comment: @terdon how do you change it? in need it to be 20 on my ubuntu or wine fails.

Comment: I don't like this answer either. Again, you can restart any process and circumvent this idiotic restriction. In short it least for me the question has **not** been answered.

Answer (score 24):

It's for what I'd call **policy reasons**.  The idea is that normal users can't override the actions of privileged users.

Let's say you're a user on some enormous shared server.  You're running monstrous CPU-hogging processes to the detriment of the other users.  The sysadmin `renice`s some of your processes because he doesn't like you very much.  The OS doesn't remember who did the `renice`, but it does know that normal users can't reverse the action.  In this way, the sysadmin has control over normal users' process priorities.

Comment: I can understand that but it still seems strange. In fact, I just realized that it's even listed as a bug in `man renice`.

Comment: I think the point of the bug is that 'Non super-users can not increase scheduling priorities of their own processes, **even if they were the ones that decreased the priorities in the first place**'.  i.e. it's a side-effect of this enforcement that an accidental `renice` can't be reversed except by a privileged user.

Comment: Yeah, but that's exactly my question, _why_? I should be allowed to play with the niceness of my processes within the range I have access to (0-20).

Comment: Because the system doesn't remember who set the priority.  Ideally, if you raised the nice level and then wanted to lower it, that would be permitted... but the system imposes a blanket prohibition precisely because it doesn't keep records of who niced what, so that you can't undo a `renice` that `root` did.

Comment: @Flup @terdon What I don't understand, and what I believe terdon is getting at, is that there is no reason why a spiteful super-user (SU) in need of CPU should _need_ to _lower_ your processes' prios. He has the full nice value range available to him, and it is easier for him to `renice` his single starved process to -10 than to renice all users' processes' prios to +10. Shouldn't a user be allowed full control of his prioritization within the subrange of nice values available to him? _SU_ meanwhile should have access to the full range, with the highest prios reserved for him exclusively.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist think of systems with many users. The sysadmin may want to raise the priority of your processes to 5 and lower those of mine to 10. That's still within the range of normal users but I won't be able to change it and steal the CPU time you deserve. That's the idea anyway as Flup explained. However, as StephaneChazelas [explained](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/119312/22222), this is configurable so it's up to the sysadmin to choose what they prefer.

Comment: The answer to “why?” is simply most likely to be “because no one needed it enough to write the code to fix it.”  When Unix was originally written, tracking who set the priority of a process might have been expensive in terms of memory usage and work to update it, but on modern machines, that's negligible, just leaving lack of motivation for writing the code to track this for sites that want to keep the original policy of “user can't override sysadmin.”

Comment: This answer doesn't sound logical **at all**. You can restart any process and get back to 0.