# Different between `ulimit -e` and `renice`?

Tags: process, limit, ulimit, nice, ionice

I would like to run a backup script in low CPU and disk I/O.

Is there any different between this:

```
#!/bin/bash

ulimit -e 19
ionice -c3 -p $$
```

and this:

```
#!/bin/bash

ionice -c3 -p $$
renice -n 19 -p $$
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is big difference between them.

- `ulimit -e` only set the `RLIMIT_NICE`, which is a upper bound value to which the process's nice value can be set using `setpriority` or `nice`.
- `renice` alters the priority of running process.

Doing `strace`:

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

ulimit -e 19
```

Then:

```
$ strace ./test.sh
...................................................
read(255, "#!/bin/bash\n\nulimit -e 19\n", 26) = 26
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
getrlimit(RLIMIT_NICE, {rlim_cur=0, rlim_max=0}) = 0
getrlimit(RLIMIT_NICE, {rlim_cur=0, rlim_max=0}) = 0
setrlimit(RLIMIT_NICE, {rlim_cur=19, rlim_max=19}) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
read(255, "", 26)                       = 0
exit_group(0)
```

You can see, `ulimit` only call `setrlimit` syscall to change the value of `RLIMIT_NICE`, nothing more.

**Note**

- [man setrlimit](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit)
- [A good explanation about `RLIMIT_NICE`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119303/why-cant-i-use-renice-to-increase-a-process-nice-value)